# Android Studio 3.2.1 is not properly indenting layout XML

Tags: xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am having an annoying issue with the latest Android Studio, version 3.2.1. Before updating it, when I was assigning constraints, the code generated would be properly organized, with each property below the other, separating the margins and the constraints, like this one, for instance:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/pb_loading_users"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

But now, it's all messy and it's not automatically placing one property per line, but two per line and I dislike it:

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="64dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp" app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"  app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
```

It's a waste of time to manually organize. Is it a bug or something I can fix myself?

Comment: @Amit Vaghela: I think that this question is not duplicate.

Comment: Ok, answers is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53196252/3115881

Comment: Go to Editor > Code style > XML  then on Scheme switch to Default instead of Project.

Comment: Thanks @Badr your comment came just in time.Maybe post it as an answer for better visibility

Comment: Yes @KennedyKambo you will find my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55211711/2354845

Answer (score 0):

*Not the real answer but a method how to bring the code to a proper format with just three key strokes.*

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it automatically reformat the code will save you your manual work.

Comment: Not exactly. This will not make the properties of the tag be below each other as it should be done automatically when selecting a tag from the autocomplete dropdown or assigning constraints. I am sure it is a bug and shall be fixed soon.