# Android Studio 3.2.1, XML bad indent format

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-studio-3.2

After updating to Android Studio 3.2.1 the XML files format is very annoying and bad, how can we fix it? Can we change it from somewhere in settings to previews type?

[image: new format]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can edit your code styles under File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML

[image: Code Style Settings]

If you want to preview a specific file, just paste that file's contents into the preview window.

Comment: thanks, I accept this as answer, but it dosn't fix when createing new view in xml, the code is in one line, height, width,....

Answer (score 31):

On Android Studio 3, Go to :

**Preferences > Editor > Code style > XML**  then on **Scheme** switch to ***Default*** instead of ***Project***.

You can then use those shortcuts to indent your code:

Windows:

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

macOS:

> <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Comment: Thank you thank you so much. I hated that stupid formatting.

Comment: Instead of what is in this answer you have to switch to Project instead of Default in new installed studio 3.6.1

Answer (score 10):

Open `File > Settings > Editor > Code Style > XML`

Now in layout file make sure you have selected wrap attributes as **Wrap always**.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NH2sK.png)